# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 LoginActivity

Tags: android, json, web-services, authentication, logcat

I'm trying to run this application but when I try to log in, I see this error in the "logcat". The message "Success Login" indicates that it has been logged and there is a connection to the database, but I don't know where would be waiting an object and where is receiving a string.

> 10-11 14:54:10.481 2532-7430/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   D/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural.http.RestJsonService: Respuesta data
>   : stdClass Object ( [login] => stdClass Object
>   (
>   [email] => kat@e.com
>   [password] => 123
>   ) )
>   SELECT id, name, email, urlImg  FROM usuario WHERE email='kat@e.com'
>   AND password='123'
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: password in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\culturapp\login.php** on line **40**
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: password in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\culturapp\login.php** on line **40**
>                                                                                                                        {"success":true,"message":"Success
>   Login","user":{"id":"26","name":"kat","email":"kat@e.com","urlImg":""}}
>
> 10-11 14:54:10.541 2532-2532/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   E/LoginActivity: error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected
>   BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
>
> 10-11 14:54:10.551 2532-2532/com.alvardev.demos.limacultural
>   E/HttpClient: NO SERVICES

//LoginActivity

```
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user = eteUser.getText().toString();
            String pass = etePassword.getText().toString();

            if (validateLogin(user, pass)) {
                RequestLogin login = new RequestLogin(new LoginEntity(user,pass));
                layLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                connectPost(DOMAIN + "login.php", gson.toJson(login), Const.LOGIN);
            }

        }
    });
```

//BaseActionBarActivity

public void connectPost(String url, String json, int action){

```
    Intent intentService = new Intent(this, RestJsonService.class);


    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString(RestJsonService.LLAVE_CONTENIDO_PETICION,json);
    parameters.putParcelable(RestJsonService.LLAVE_RECIBIDOR,resultReceiver);
    parameters.putInt(RestJsonService.LLAVE_METODO_PETICION, HttpMethod.POST.getValue());
    parameters.putString(RestJsonService.LLAVE_URL, url);
    parameters.putInt(RestJsonService.LLAVE_TIPO_ACCION, action);

    intentService.putExtras(parameters);
    startService(intentService);
}
```

//RestJsonService

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

```
    Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando servicio");
    String url = null;
    String datos = null;
    int metodo = 0;
    int tipoAccion = 0;
    HttpResult resultado = null;

    Bundle parametros = intent.getExtras();

    url = parametros.getString(LLAVE_URL);
    datos = parametros.getString(LLAVE_CONTENIDO_PETICION);
    metodo = parametros.getInt(LLAVE_METODO_PETICION);
    tipoAccion = parametros.getInt(LLAVE_TIPO_ACCION);

    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada a la url " + url);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada con datos " + datos);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada metodo " + metodo);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada tipoaccion " + tipoAccion);

    ResultReceiver recibidor = parametros.getParcelable(LLAVE_RECIBIDOR);

    HttpMethod metodoEnum = HttpMethod.forValue(metodo);
    Log.d(TAG, "Llamada " + metodoEnum.toString());
    switch (metodoEnum) {
        case POST:
            Log.d(TAG, "antes por el post");

            resultado = postJson(datos, url);


            break;
        case GET:
            resultado = getJson(url);
            Log.d(TAG, "paso por el get");

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Respuesta codigo : " + resultado.getStatusCode());

    Log.d(TAG, "Respuesta data : " + resultado.getData());

    Bundle datosResultado = new Bundle();
    datosResultado
            .putString(LLAVE_CONTENIDO_RESPUESTA, resultado.getData());
    datosResultado.putInt(LLAVE_TIPO_ACCION, tipoAccion);

    recibidor.send(resultado.getStatusCode(), datosResultado);
    //recibidor = null;
}
```

private HttpResult postJson(String bodyRequest, String url) {

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    String data = null;
    int status = 0;

    StringEntity se;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(bodyRequest, "UTF8");
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json"));
        Log.d(TAG, "text/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);



        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String respuesta = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        data = respuesta;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        status = HttpCode.ERROR.getCode();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error protocolo");
        Log.e(TAG, getErrorMessage(e, "Error al realizar la peticion"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error timeout");
        Log.e(TAG, getErrorMessage(e, "Timeout sucedio"));
        status = HttpCode.TIMEOUT.getCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error general");

        Log.e(TAG,
                getErrorMessage(e,
                        "Error generico sucedio al realizar la petici�n"));
        status = HttpCode.ERROR.getCode();
    }

    return new HttpResult(data, status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have sample of bad implementation of server side api.
Actually if api responds with `json` then must always respond with `json`. As for me it's bad practice to send one time string and another - serialized `json`.

good practice as for me is all responds like:

```
{"success":true, "data": "some data object optional"}
{"success":false, "error":{"errorCode":123, "errorMessage":"some error text"}, data:"some additional data object optional"}
```

to be sure you got proper respond `hmac` request signing could be implemented - so you will check and deserialize only if `hmac` sign is correct, to be sure respond is ok and you got your `json`. Coz without check you are not sure what you got, you can got error text as string from server and you will try to deserialize it with `Gson`.

in anyway you can catch all with `try/catch` but above is proper way described )

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from Gson, when you're trying to parse the string response to a JSON. It's a typical error when the string provided is not a valid JSON, but a plain string. The error comes from this part, probably:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 connectPost(DOMAIN + "login.php", gson.toJson(login), Const.LOGIN);
```

You're trying to convert to JSON the `login` object:

```
            RequestLogin login = new RequestLogin(new LoginEntity(user,pass));
```

And the String representation of that object is not a JSON. You're not sharing the code of the `RequestLogin` class - but try to modify your code to provide a valid JSON to Gson. What you are providing now is the `toString()` output of the RequestLogin class - which is not a valid JSON.

Can you share the content of `gson.toJson(login)`?